# can I prevent Chrome from truncating strings in the dev console?

Tags: google-chrome

```
> ary = new Array('test msg kinda long but gets the point across and such and it shows ellipsises after a certain point in my test. test msg kinda long but gets the point across and such and it shows ellipsises after a certain point in my test. test msg kinda long but gets the point across and such and it shows ellipsises after a certain point in my test. test msg kinda long but gets the point across and such and it shows ellipsises after a certain point in my test. test msg kinda long but gets the point across and such and it shows ellipsises after a certain point in my test.');
> JSON.stringify(ary)
"["test msg kinda long but gets the point across and such and it shows ellipsises... (length: 116)"
```

I really want the full object, but Chrome wants to trim the result at about 80 characters. I don't see anything in the console settings that would change this.

Comment: I solve this by clicking 'View Page Source'

Comment: That doesn't work for JavaScript objects

Answer (score 69, accepted):

I recently discovered that the Chrome dev tools has a `copy` function which copies to clipboard - without truncation! Handily it also serializes objects to JSON and DOM elements to HTML, straight to the clipboard.

```
copy(someLongString); // no truncation!
copy({ foo : true }); // JSON
copy(someDOMElement); // HTML
```

Since I was trying to copy a long string to clipboard for analysis elsewhere, this served my needs perfectly

**Edit in 2021**: Seems Chrome now adds a handy button in console for copying long strings:

[image: screenshot of chrome's new "Copy" button in console]

Here's some code to test the feature:

```js
var str = ""; 

// generate 30kb hex string
for(var i = 0; i < (1024 * 30); i++) { 
  str += (i % 16).toString(16) 
}; 

// just so we know it copied the whole thing
str += "END";
```

Comment: that's slick; doesn't really answer the question though, should be a comment instead

Comment: +1 this is so useful. Granted it doesn't technically answer the question but it solves the problem causing the question to be asked - how to get the full, untruncated text from the console. Just paste it into a text editor and you're sorted.

Comment: I got in Chrome: Uncaught ReferenceError: copy is not defined

Comment: @arod it's only available in the console, not gobally

Comment: @WickyNilliams - I've always hated that - I can imagine some super helpful uses for it.

Comment: This works in Firefox too.

Comment: @Björn didn't realise that. Good to know!

Comment: Doesn't work. Still truncates text for very large string. 20 kb in my case.

Comment: @PankajPhartiyal It 100% works. Here's some test code to prove it: `var str = ""; for(var i = 0; i < (1024*30); i++) { str += (i % 16).toString(16) }; str += "END"; copy(str)` - creates 30kb hex string, with "END" at the end to be sure it worked. Be aware e.g. vscode will truncate long lines itself. Set editor to wrap lines and you will see the whole thing

Comment: Nope.  It truncates the string for me, even if I click Copy.

Comment: @Jez works for me still, I just tested again

Answer (score 30):

`console.dir(longstringhere)` works.

`copy` didn't work for me either, it was saying it's `undefined`.

Comment: Same here. 'console.copy' didn't work but 'console.dir' worked. You saved my day.

Comment: `copy` function does not output anything (hence `undefined` is expected), instead it copies argument to your system buffer, just paste it (`ctrl-v`) into any editor

Comment: not working....

Comment: You must copy from the console e.g. place a breakpoint where the value is, open console, type `copy(yourVariable)`. Also, it's just `copy` not `console.copy`

Comment: Every function in JS returns undefined if not specified. So it actually works.

Comment: Obviously the function returns `undefined`, but I suspect he means that when he *pastes* he gets `undefined`. This happens if `longstringhere` isn't actually a string - check `typeof longstringhere`.

Comment: I just tried it, it works with objects.

Answer (score 6):

This behavior still exists in Chrome Version 37.0.2062.103.

You can get around this while debugging by using:  document.write('My Really Long Debug Text');

Comment: 37.0.2062.120 m on Windows 7: no ellipses.

Comment: Not working anymore..

Comment: Nov 2021: Chrome is now version 95. Holy crap they increment their major version a lot.

Answer (score 4):

I use the following:

```
var text = 'a really long string';
window.prompt("Copy to clipboard", text);
```

then copy the text from the edit field.

Comment: This is also truncated

Answer (score 3):

Upgrade Chrome to version 32 which no longer does this, as shown by this picture:

[image]

Comment: chrome canary v36+... it still does that. ...but now does not show the length. e.g. `long string...ends here`.

Comment: You're in a version of chrome that hasn't been released yet. It's not happening in v33 on Ubuntu: http://imgur.com/RPCgR6f -- did you downvote me because my solution didn't fix your problem even though you're in a pre-release version?!

Comment: well, don't get too used to it :) seriously i downvoted because it does not really solve the problem. running an old browser version is not possible for most and probably insecure after some time. (current stable google-chrome is 34.0.1847.134) but don't get iffy on that, i'm also looking for a solution. the goal here is to collect solutions not imaginary internet points. I would have upvoted if you commented that it does not happen on v33. it is a usefull observation, but not a solution.

Comment: "solve the problem. running an old browser version is not possible " --- it's not an old browser version! I'm up to date and at v33 in ubuntu. My windows box is up to date and it's v34. I don't know where you're getting v36 from. "it does not happen on v33" -- and it doesn't, which the screenshot (from v33) proves.

Comment: the key takeaway is that this bug/behaviour was inserted back after 33 or 34.

Comment: That's nice. You should submit a bug report. Since the current *released* version of Chrome doesn't have it, you shouldn't downvote me for saying updating to the newest *released* version of Chrome fixes it. And that holds true for V34 on Win7 and V33 on Ubuntu.

Comment: windoes, chrome 47, still ellipsis

Comment: Chrome 49 on mac, no ellipsis

Comment: Chrome 56 - ellipsis in the ***middle*** of the string

Answer (score 3):

The length of the string that is rendered to the console is limited
programatically inside inspector.js. It's set to 150 characters by default.
There's no CSS you can apply because it is being rendered to the console as
HTML. The text has already been truncated.

You can change it but it's going to take a little bit of work:

## Necessary and Helpful Tools:

• ack (brew install ack) or ag. (for searching huge text files really fast).

• paktools for python. For unpacking the chrome resources to be able to edit them. https://github.com/Magister/pak-tools.

• text editor of choice.

1. cd or navigate into whatever version of Chrome you have. I am using Chromium
   as an example but the path is the same on other versions:

   ```
   cd "/Applications/Chromium.app/Contents/Versions/YOURVERSION/Chromium Framework.framework/Resources/"
   ```
2. Clone or download the paktools. This will allow your to unpack the chrome
   resources, edit them and then repack them. I placed mine in my `~./bin` but
   you can put them anywhere. Examples will mirror my path:
3. Now in the `Chrome/.../Chrome Framework.framework/Resoures` folder execute:
   `python2 ~/.bin/unpack.py resources.pak` and `cd ./resouces`
4. You're going to have to find where it is. The files change all the time and so it's never the same. 
   `$ ag "static linkify"` That took me to `28542`. I modified the function to default to 2000 chars, and also updated
   the css so I could scroll horizontally in the console.
5. now cd back out of the resouces folder you unpacked and into it's parent. Execute: 
   `python2 ~/.bin/pack.py resources` and voila. Restart Chrome and your devtools are now custom.

WARNING: 
6. The devtools team pushes out updates the framework's versions without you knowing. And you'll lose all your mods if they do. I block it by 
executing `/Users/Op/Library/Google/GoogleSoftwareUpdate/GoogleSoftwareUpdate.bundle/Contents/Resources/ksinstall --uninstall` and killing all the
keystone deamons etc.

Works like a charm.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In Chrome 58 (maybe earlier) you can use the `Store as Global Variable` menu option on the contextual menu of any value in the console, nested at any level. It assigns the selected value to a variable with a unique name, which is immediately logged to the console.

Just tried it on a 400KB value!

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41726364/250838

Comment: Good solution +1

Answer (score 1):

For strings inside of a `<script>` tag, none of the existing answers work and the output remains truncated. However you can find your full string in the Sources tab - just switch to the tab and CTRL + F search for part of your string.

Answer (score 0):

After getting fed up with Chrome truncating everything I finally just threw the json I needed into a dom element. It is definately not the most elegant solution, but it works when you really need the output.

```
const div = document.createElement('div')
div.innerText = JSON.stringify(data)
document.body.appendChild(div)
```